# SED, GREP, AWK, regex do not display content between two patterns contain and match a string inside on the second occurrence pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Is there a way to not display a block between two patterns when it matches a string inside the block and only to the 2nd occurrence of the second pattern?

example :

```
test, test-xxx-a2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.x.x
+               value: x.3.x
...
test, test-xxxio-3, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-   replicas: 3
+   replicas: 5
...

test, test-xxx-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: x.2.x
+               value: x.x.x
...
test, test-xxxio-1, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-   replicas: 3
+   replicas: 5
...

test, test-xxxio-4, Deployment (apps) has add:
...

text...

...

test, test-xxx-test2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-   replicas: 3
+   replicas: 2
...
text, text-123-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-   replicas: 1
+   replicas: 2
...
-               value: 2.1.0
+               value: 42.4.0
...
```

Output desire:

```
test, test-xxx-a2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.x.x
+               value: x.3.x
...

test, test-xxx-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: x.2.x
+               value: x.x.x
...

test, test-xxxio-4, Deployment (apps) has add:
...

text...

...
text, text-123-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 2.1.0
+               value: 42.4.0
...
```

first pattern: `changed:`

second pattern: `...`  (only the second)

string in to contain: `replicas`

the regex I'm working https://regex101.com/r/FTGBxG/1, but of course, it's not my output desire.

Comment: The end of your sample input appears to be messed up, take a look and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v ORS= '
    { buf = buf $0 RS }
    ($0 == "...") && ((++sepCnt % 2) == 0) {
        if ( buf !~ /replicas/ ) {
            print buf
        }
        buf=""
    }
' file
test, test-xxx-a2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.x.x
+               value: x.3.x
...

test, test-xxx-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: x.2.x
+               value: x.x.x
...

test, test-xxxio-4, Deployment (apps) has add:
...

text...

...
```

Comment: ++ This is very good solution shorter than mine

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` script:

```sh
cat filter.awk

index($0, "Deployment (apps)") {
   p = 1
   s = ""
   num3dots = 0
}

p {s = s $0 ORS}

index($0, "...") == 1 && ++num3dots == 2 {
   if ( s !~ /changed:.* replicas/ )
      printf "%s", s
   p = 0
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f filter.awk file

test, test-xxx-a2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.x.x
+               value: x.3.x
...
test, test-xxx-xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: x.2.x
+               value: x.x.x
...
test, test-xxxio-4, Deployment (apps) has add:
...

text...

...
```

Comment: Good point Ed. I have fixed it now.